# SQL help in calculating regular and overtime hours for project billing

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My table looks like this

```
First Name  Last Name   Date    Day Hours   Project Name
Joe         Smith     6/22/15   Mon 8       Project A
Joe         Smith     6/23/15   Tue 11.75   Project A
Joe         Smith     6/24/15   Wed 10.25   Project A
Joe         Smith     6/25/15   Thu 14.25   Project B
Joe         Smith     6/26/15   Fri 11.5    Project B
Joe         Smith     6/27/15   Sat 9.5     Project B
Joe         Smith    6/28/15    Sun 8.53    Project B
```

I need to calculate regular time and overtime hours from this for each employee and each project worked.

Regular time :All week day hours for the week less than or equal to 40 hours
Overtime: Week-day hours over 40, any weekend hours

My result should be like this

```
Firstname   Lastname    Date    Day Regular OverTime    Project Name
Joe          Smith     6/22/15  Mon 8.00                 Project A
Joe          Smith     6/23/15  Tue 11.75                Project A
Joe          Smith     6/24/15  Wed 10.25                Project A
Joe          Smith     6/25/15  Thu 10.00   4.25         Project B
Joe          Smith     6/26/15  Fri 0.00    11.50        Project B
Joe          Smith     6/27/15  Sat 0.00    9.50         Project B
Joe          Smith     6/28/15  Sun 0.00    8.53         Project B
--------------------------------------------------------------------
    Total                           40.00   33.78
```

I am unable to achieve this result.

Comment: Your SQL engine supports windowed partitions? (Over clause )

Comment: No it doesnt. I dont have to display the total part. Just the overtime and regular time  calculation

Comment: without window functions the solution is really horrid.  what SQL does it need to work in?

Comment: microsoft sql 2008 server

Comment: cant we do it by running total

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a SQL server, below code will work. Please note that I am using COALESCE keyword to encapsulate the business logic for OverTime and Regular hours calculation. 
For these calculations I needed the cumulative hours in the week calculated using inner query, as well I needed to identify point of inflexion when the hours went past 40.

```
SELECT 
Q.FirstName, 
Q.LastName,
Q.[Date],
Q.Day,
COALESCE(
      CASE 
         WHEN Q.[Day] like 's%' THEN 0 ELSE NULL END,
       CASE 
         WHEN Q.Cumulative>40 AND Q.cumulative-Q.hours>40 
         THEN 0 ELSE NULL END,
       CASE 
          WHEN Q.Cumulative>40 AND Q.cumulative-Q.hours<40 
          THEN 40-Q.cumulative+ Q.hours ELSE Q.hours END
        ) AS Regular,
COALESCE(
      CASE 
         WHEN Q.[Day] like 's%' THEN Q.Hours ELSE NULL END,
       CASE 
         WHEN Q.Cumulative>40 AND Q.cumulative-Q.hours>40
         THEN Q.hours ELSE NULL END,
       CASE 
          WHEN Q.Cumulative>40 AND Q.cumulative-Q.hours<40 
          THEN Q.Cumulative-40 ELSE 0 END
        ) AS OverTime,
Q.[Project Name]
FROM
(SELECT 
B.FirstName,
B.LastName,
B.[Date],
B.Day,
B.hours,
B.[Project Name],
(SELECT SUM(A.hours) FROM  [dbo].[temp] A WHERE A.[Date]<=B.[Date]) cumulative
FROM [dbo].[temp] B )Q
```

Sql fiddle link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7eea7/2

Comment: your answer is very helpful but Regular time is calculating 0

Comment: Did you have a look at the Sqlfiddle in the answer? For Mon-Thur, there are some hours under Regular Hours column. Is there more to requirements that what is encapsulated as logic in the COALESCE function.

Comment: According to your SQL Fiddle, this query doesn't produce the results originally requested.  In fact, summing the column "Regular" correctly produces 40, but summing the "OverTime" column produces an incorrect result of 63.78, instead of 33.78.

Comment: @STLDeveloper Thank you for bringing it to attention. I've updated the fiddle and the answer. See revisions here [https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31541540/revisions]